ifelse statement on all variables in R
I have this dataset but really larger (more variables, more individuals).
a <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3)
b <- c(NA, 1, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA)
c <- c(NA, NA, 2, NA, 1, 2, NA)
d <- c(NA, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, 3)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)

I would like to create three new variables x, y and z.
x should be 1 if there is at least one column containing 1 (a, b, c or d).
y should be 1 if there is at least one column containing 2 (a, b, c or d).
z should be 1 if there is at least one column containing 3 (a, b, c, or d).
Is there a way to do it in an optimized way? I have more than 50 cols (not only the 4 in this min example) to which it has to be applied. I tried to create a function but it was unsuccessful.

Here is a function to do this. Essentially, iterate over the columns and take the rowSums() of the relevant comparison.
get_xyz <- function(df, cols = names(df), new_cols = c("x", "y", "z")) {
    df[new_cols] <- lapply(
        seq_along(new_cols),
        \(x) +(rowSums(df[cols] == x, na.rm = TRUE) > 0)
    )
    df
}

Used as follows:
get_xyz(df)
#    a  b  c  d x y z
# 1 NA NA NA NA 0 0 0
# 2 NA  1 NA  1 1 0 0
# 3 NA  2  2  2 0 1 0
# 4 NA  3 NA NA 0 0 1
# 5  1 NA  1 NA 1 0 0
# 6  2 NA  2 NA 0 1 0
# 7  3 NA NA  3 0 0 1


Thanks a lot, meanwhile, an AI solved the problem in two seconds. :-p df$x<- apply(constats, 1, function(row) ifelse(any(row == 1), 1, 0)) and did it two more times only for the other. But still I get this question, what is the 1 margin here?

I think AI gave you an answer in two seconds but it is not exactly what you need (from your description)

Found it meanwhile and it works. Still don't get what the 1 margin does?
df$x<- apply(constats, 1, function(row) ifelse(any(row == 1), 1, 0))

Margin = 1 applies the function to rows. Margin = 2 applies it to columns. I also don’t think this code is 100% correct for what you want

Except it looks from that code that you want to have either a 1 or a 0 but that will return 1  or NA in any row your data has NA values. Also row-wise iteration will be noticeably slower on any reasonably-sized data frame.

this also will not created your variables y and z

Well indeed but 0 or NA will have the same result in the end, so basically I'll get the same :-) And I just copy/paste it for y and z.

Your question asked for an optimized approach - this is not optimized at all and provides incorrect results (in contrast to SamR’s answer, which does implement a correct and optimized approach). Also note that ChatGPT-assisted answers are banned on Stack Overflow- see link for more info
